# Built in function that constructs TSize?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Is there a built-in function in Delphi 7 that returns a `TSize` from a given `cx` and `cy` parameters?

Something similar to the functions `Rect()` and `Point()` etc...

I know that writing my own is very simple (although its a shame that `Size` is already an alias to `TSize` so I can't name *my* function `Size`). but I was wondering if there is a **build-in** function in the RTL.

Comment: Why not just use `TSize.Create(cx, cy)` ?

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy, how? `TSize` is a record type in Delphi 7. it has not `Create` method and records does not support methods or helpers in D7.

Comment: Ok, my bad. Didn't see the Delphi 7 tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such built in function in the Delphi 7 RTL.

Comment: Is there a **function** like this in newer versions? and I don't mean `TSize.Create(cx, cy)`.

Comment: @Zig, no, there is not a standalone function even in recent version (Tokyo).

Comment: @Victoria, Thanks. As a bonus question, do you think *naming* such function as `GetSize(cx,  cy)` is good convention?

Comment: I don't. `GetXXX` is used to indicate reading state. Here you are initializing something new.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Thanks. maybe `SizeInit` or `SizeCreate`? too bad I can't use `Size()` :/

Comment: I'd use `Size`. You aren't going to need the type `SIZE` so you can hide it. In the same way that the RTL hides the types `RECT`, `POINT` etc. with functions of the same name that return newly minted values.

Comment: Great! I didn't think of that!

Comment: But if you really want to avoid a name clash/hide, call it `MakeSize`. That clearly indicates what the function does, IMO.